# Why Jquery pop up it's not woking on Server

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

Jquery dialog is not working on IIS Server but in my local machine below code was working fine. In server the mapped url is not working it's throwing error like '404 resource is not found ' like that.

> Jquery Code

```
$('#new dialog')dialog({
            auto-open: false,
            width: 345,

           top: 76,
            re sizable: false,
            title: 'Add Ad Details',
            modal: true,
            open: function (event, ui) {
                $(this)load("../Ad/ad Manage?atype=" + adtype);
            },
            buttons: false,
            position: {
                my: 'top',
                at: 'top',
                of: $('.maindiv')
            }

        });
        //---------------------------------
        $('.clk')click(function () {
            $('body,HTML').addClass('hide scrolls');
            $.ajaxSetup({
                // Disable caching of AJAX responses */
                cache: false
            });
            idimg = $(this).attr('id');
            $('#dialog').dialog('open');
        });
        $('.tp').click(function () {
            $('body,html').addClass('hidescrolls');
            $.ajaxSetup({
                // Disable caching of AJAX responses */
                cache: false
            });
            adtype = $(this).attr('id');
            $('#newdialog').dialog('open');
        });
```

Above code was working on my local machine but in server it's not working,I'm getting the error like 'resource not found error' could you please tell me where i need to change in above code reference.

Comment: what error u getting??? alert url from   $(this).load("../Ad/adManage?atype=" + adtype);

Comment: you should be also mentioning, what are you trying to do and whats happening

Comment: Hooray! You have some code. Congrats! How about you give us a good description of your error and what you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

not sure if this is correct, but in your script where it says ('id'), shouldn't you be putting an #ID in there?

Comment: My exact  question issue is Jquery Dialog which is not working on server do u know any other alternate way to opening the dialog by using jquery..?

Comment: I have a similar pop up on my page - the div that contains the information on my page, that will go in the popup, looks like this: <div id="mydialog" title="status changes" class="popUpchanges" >content....</div>

Comment: at the end of my page, right before closing the body tag, I have the script:
<script>
    $('#mydialog').dialog({
 autoOpen:false,
 resizable: false,
 width: 935,
 height: 370,
 modal: true,
 buttons: { 
  //Cancel: function() {
  //$( this ).dialog( "close" ); 
  //},
  "Return": function() {
  $('#update-alien').load('actions)
   $( this ).dialog( "close" ); 
 }
 },

Comment: create:function () {
       // $(this).closest(".ui-dialog").find(".ui-button:first").addClass("app_button_gray"); 
  $(this).closest(".ui-dialog").find(".ui-button").eq(1).addClass("app_button") // The return/second button
    }
 });
 $( ".confirmBtn" )
 .click(function() {
  $( "#mydialog" ).dialog( "open" );

 });

Answer (score 0):

for creating url use MVC function:

```
var actionUrl = '@Url.Action("ACTION_NAME", "CONTROLLER_NAME", new { adType = "ADTYPE" })';
actionUrl = actionUrl.replace("ADTYPE",adtype);
```

and use it:

```
$(this)load(actionUrl);
```

and one thing I observed you passing query string `atype` while variable say it `adtype` it should be same as your server side function expecting it.